# Getting Symfony base URL from a service?

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, base-url

I have a service that needs to access the current application base URL (what's returned by `app.request.getBaseURL()` in Twig views). Currently, my config is like this:

```
services:
    WidgetModel:
        class: AppBundle\Model\WidgetModel
        scope: prototype
        arguments: ['%widgets%']
```

So as a second argument, I would like to inject the base URL. Is it possible? If not, what would be proper solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no builtin base url service.  Which is actually a bit of a red flag that maybe having your component depending on it might not be such a good idea.  But I can't think of a good reason why.

So normally, one would just inject the request object.  But that has it's own problems as documented here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Instead, inject the @request_stack service and pull the url from it:

```
class WidgetModel
{
  public __construct($widgets,$requestStack)
  {
    $this->baseUrl = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getBaseUrl();
```

If you do find yourself needing the baseUrl in multiple services then you could define your own factory type service to generate it.  But again, that might mean your design needs rethinking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [expression language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language) in your service definition.

This example should do what you want:

```
services:
    WidgetModel:
        class: AppBundle\Model\WidgetModel
        scope: prototype
        arguments: [%widgets%, "@=service('request').getBaseUrl()"]
```

It fetches the request service and then executes the `getBaseUrl` method.

You will need to add a second parameter in your `WigetModel` for the base URL.

Comment: Have you tried this?  Accessing the request directly as a service seldom works as expected.  It will definitely not work in S3.x.   It might work using request_stack.

Comment: Yes, I created a simple Symfony 2.7 project with the OP's `WidgetModel` class and was able to inject just the base URL. Do you have a link to anything that shows the migration path for 3.x?

Comment: "In Symfony 3.0, we will fix the problem once and for all by removing the request service from the container." http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack.  You can keep up with what is going on in Symfony here: http://symfony.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer, in Symfony 3 you can use request_stack to get the base url using [expressions languages (updated link)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html) such as:

```
services:
    WidgetModel:
        class: AppBundle\Model\WidgetModel
        scope: prototype
        arguments: [%widgets%,"@=service('request_stack').getCurrentRequest().getBaseUrl()"
```